# Is there a list of 3rd party angulardart modules?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Anyone know of a list of 3rd party angulardart modules, something similar to http://ngmodules.org/ but for angulardart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search on pub.dartlang.org for Angular.

https://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=angular